# navigateToConversation Function not found

Tags: circuit-sdk

I have tried to implement the navigateToConversation Function into my Programm but it is telling me that the function does not exist.

I have allready succesfully signed in and can getConversations as well as addItems.

```
client.navigateToConversation('5af91241-dd21-42a4-ade4-370c5e32907f')
                            .then(() => console.log('Navigate to Conversation'))
```

The convId is a real one as i have previosly written to it using the SDK.

[The Error produced by calling the Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1vWP.png)

I am also using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Circuit SDK has been updated on npm and unpkg. The function is now available.
https://unpkg.com/circuit-sdk

Comment: If i use the function and the function is not trying to open a new tab but targeting an existing device, i allways get a PERMISION_DENIED error.

Comment: Your app needs the USER_TO_USER scope. This is a special scope that cannot be set by the tenant admin via the UI at this time. The system admin needs to add that scope to the application. You can go via the help desk if you are referring to the production system. If its for the sandbox let me know your client_id and I can add that permission for you.

Comment: I am currently woirking with ther sandbox. My Client ID is: 0413af319aa1444bae845d41e93dec7c

Comment: Make sure you use the latest Circuit SDK. Here is a jsbin that works fine. You can change the client_id to yours if you want to test with your sandbox tenant.
https://output.jsbin.com/sikumuj/

Comment: I have tried the jsbin and it does not work. If i use the supplied client_id the OAuth popup is throwing me for a loop and when I use my client_id i am told that a requested scope is not available. I am guessing that with my client this the USER_TO_USER scope as every other scope is given by my application.

Comment: I had posted the wrong jsbin, here is the right one: https://output.jsbin.com/cagiyuc
Also, this is in a demo tenant do you can use the demo user: kim.jackson@mailinator.com / GoCircuit!1

I also added the USER_TO_USER scope to the client_id you posted above.

Comment: The jsbin is now working i think adding the USER_TO_USER scope did not work as i still get PERMISSION_DENIED in my application as well as the jsbin when using my client_id.

Comment: Did you fork the jsbin and try your client_id, and your credentials? If that does nt work I need to test with a user on your tenenat. Do you mind if I create a new user on your tenant to test that you can then delete? Or you rather give credentials of a user in your tenant to test?

Comment: I tried both my own application as well as the jsbin again and now everything works. I do not know why but thank you for your help.